# JavaScript Text Swa-per

Tags: javascript, html

I need assistance in creating a viable Text Swap-er.
My project needs to manipulate a fixed and dynamic site-map in order to appeal to the majority of users, and to limit hassle.
A `<p>` element is placed in the top-right corner of the page, fixed in place, when pressed will change it's text and switch the presentation mode to dynamic or fixed, depending on which was pressed last.

That's the part I am stuck on. Interpreting which mode was just activated is a trouble for me: my attempts have been nothing but futile...

```
var parent = document.getElementById("changeInteractiveness")
parent.onclick = function(){textDynamic()}
function textDynamic() {
    parent.innerHTML = "<b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Fixed"
    parent.onclick = "textFixed()"
    // Call Interactive-Mode : Coming Soon
}
function textFixed() {
    parent.innerHTML = "<b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Dynamic"
    parent.onclick = "textDynamic()"
    // Call back Fixed-Mode : Coming Soon
}
```

The 'changeInteractiveness' Id, is what I am using for the script to distinguish what to change.
(And just in case, I also included a `onclick="textDynamic()"` statement, but that didn't work either...)

**Additionally**, when I start the page, opening the Chrome Developers' Console, I receive an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at sitemap.html:69

I fiddled around with the construct of the code, but anything that I did: like changing the calling method or assigning a dummy-parent, did not work.
Is there an error in my methods, or is it just refusing to accept my code?
Answers are appreciated.

## Expanded Upon

My question needs a lot more work. I know. :)

Anyway, the script tag and paragraph tag reside in a `div` container, inside another `div` and so on. After all, the layout of the page is important to appeal to the audience!
As far as I'm aware, it shouldn't affect anything, other than the parent and children properties (that I don't need to use).
The code that "Gaby aka G. Petrioli" provided was a sufficient work-around to the problem, yet Google Chrome (my Google Chrome, it hates me) refuses to accept this code. Shown below...

```
var parent = document.getElementById("changeInteractiveness")
parent.onclick = textDynamic;
function textDynamic() {
    parent.innerHTML = "<b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Fixed!"
    parent.onclick = textFixed;
    // Call Interactive-Mode
}
function textFixed() {
    parent.innerHTML = "<b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Dynamic!"
    parent.onclick = textDynamic;
    // Call Fixed-Mode
}
```

In theory, it should work proper. And I've tried the above in *jQuery* **too**!

```
var target = $("#changeInteractiveness")
target.on("click", function(event){
    target.html("<b>Change Interactiveness</b> ")
    target.remove(" to Fixed!")
    target.append(" to Dynamic!")
    target.on("dblclick", function(event){
        target.remove(" to Dynamic!")
        target.append(" to Fixed!")
    })
})
```

The `click` and `dblclick` are in-built identifiers to separate and minimise code length. It is included to not have to make a number counter for how many times a user clicked the button, in turn switching the mode the Dynamic or Fixed based upon whether the variable was odd or even...
Actually, thinking about it, I might as well use it if it's confirmed to actually work (though from reading my own example it seems that you'd have to click three *two* times to access Fixed Mode again!)...

Assistance is Optional - I'm sure that I can create a work-around. But your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign the function references directly to the `onclick` property 
(*not as strings*).

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("changeInteractiveness")
parent.onclick = textDynamic;

function textDynamic() {
    parent.innerHTML = "<b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Fixed"
    parent.onclick = textFixed;
    // Call Interactive-Mode : Coming Soon
}
function textFixed() {
    parent.innerHTML = "<b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Dynamic"
    parent.onclick = textDynamic;
    // Call back Fixed-Mode : Coming Soon
}
```

```html
<p id="changeInteractiveness"><b>Change Interactiveness</b> to Dynamic</p>
```

Comment: I still receive a Type Error in the console, resulting in the full result not showing. Perhaps there's something going wrong with my `<p>`? I have assigned the 'onclick' attribute as the 'textDynamic();' function...

Comment: I'm now considering using JQuery, as I'm more experienced in that... gosh, all I want to do is use traditional methods - it seems we can't do that anymore :(

Comment: @ghostwalker13 if you notice in my code I am assigning the handlers without adding the `()` at the end. This way you assign a reference to the function. With the parenthesis you actually execute the function and assign the result (*which is not what we want in this case*)

Comment: I'm still receiving Type Errors... Apparently, `onclick` needs a property. But I've already assigned one, the function call, so what now? Is Chrome trying to stop me again? ... :(

Comment: @ghostwalker13 does the example code in my answer work (*click "run code snippet"*)? If it does work, then post your current code so i can have a look (*or a live demo even better*)

Comment: I'm trying to collect a sample of the previous version of the file that I had. Since I couldn't synthesis a one-click-all-wonder button, I implemented two buttons, one for Dynamic Mode and the other for Fixed Mode. It's working well so far, just that I have to configure the CSS:visibility properties properly... About the code thing, I'll scrape up an example!